# Is there a list of DAPPS that are already useable?

Tags: dapps

Is there a list of DAPPs that are already useable?

Useable means there is an easy accessible GUI, that can interact with the contract.

Comment: There currently are no real world examples that I have found, I like to think of ethereum as being in beta.

Comment: [List questions are generally off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98334/226837) and [here is some more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11780/22683).  This has been converted to: Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion. This affects the question and all answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some that are deployed live on Frontier:

[Mist Wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases)

[Safe Market](https://safemarket.github.io)

[Gnosis - prediction market](https://groupgnosis.com)

[Alarm Clock](http://ethereum-alarm-clock.com)

[Etheria - virtual world](http://etheria.world)

[Digix - Bitcoin to Gold on Ethereum](https://dgx.io)

[Oraclize](https://oraclize.it)

There are many other dApps on testnet and other phases of development, and a list is at: http://dapps.ethercasts.com

Answer (score 8):

There are a few DAPP lists out there.

http://dapps.ethercasts.com is pretty extensive, but not all of them are easy to use or publicly available.

http://reddit.com/r/ethdapps is a bit outdated and doesn't see much activity, but there are some good example DAPPs from the early days.

https://ethereum.org/#projects has the really big official DAPP companies.

The DevCon1 Talks are great for seeing what's out there as well

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this article (linked below) from MIT Technology Review? It is a critique of a newly launched $130 million project, however it may be an interesting starting place:

https://www.technologyreview.com/s/601480/the-autonomous-corporation-called-the-dao-is-not-a-good-way-to-spend-130-million/

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum Wallet doesn't allow external URLs to be accessed, but it is the easiest way for a user to interact with Ethereum and contracts. (Current easiest official way.) So technically, this is "contracts and transferring money only, not Dapps".

Mist would allow you a similar interface to Ethereum Wallet, and allow Dapps, but would not be easy for beginner users to set up. ("Just install your node.js, download our git repo, download any dependencies, run our meteor, run electron"... a bit too much for a newb.)

I wouldn't trust any non-official easy accessible GUI.

I'd wait until Ethereum Wallet starts allowing external URLs. (If that's even the plan?) You can switch this back and forth (mist/wallet) with a single variable, but I don't think you can change it from the executable.

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea of what's going on in the community, and where various projects currently are, you could take a look at the [talks from DevCon1](https://www.youtube.com/user/ethereumproject/search?query=devcon1).

While this doesn't give an exhaustive list, and is perhaps skewed towards higher-profile groups and teams (and those that could make it to London... ), it does provide a way to get a general feel for the current DApp environment, and the trends that are being created.

(Minor caveat: DevCon1 was a couple of months ago now.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a listing of various dapps and their state of development:

http://dapps.ethercasts.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well, in this case the link *is* the answer. You can hardly maintain an updated list on stackexchange. so +1 for the link in this rare case.